# Slicing a MultiIndex DataFrame by multiple values from a specified level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I want to slice a MultiIndex [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) by multiple values from a secondary level. For example, in the following DataFrame:

```
                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3            
1    6    s1      10     8
2    7    s1      20     6
3    8    s2      30     4
4    9    s2      50     2
5    10   s3      60     0
```

I wish to slice only the rows in which `ind3 == s1` **or** `ind3 == s3`:

```
           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
1    6       10     8
2    7       20     6
5    10      60     0
```

Best hypothetical option would be to pass multiple arguments to [`.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), since it is possible to explicitly state the desired `level`.

I could obviously concat all the sliced-by-single-value DataFrames:

```
In[2]: pd.concat([df.xs('s1',level=2), df.xs('s3',level=2)])
Out[2]:
           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
1    6       10     8
2    7       20     6
5    10      60     0
```

But *(a)* it's tedious and not so readable when using more than 2 values, and *(b)* for large DataFrames it's quite heavy (or at least heavier than a multi-value slicing option, if that exists).

Here's *the code to build the example DataFrame*:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ind1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'ind2':[6,7,8,9,10], 'ind3':['s1','s1','s2','s2','s3'], 'val1':[10,20,30,50,60], 'val2':[8,6,4,2,0]}).set_index(['ind1','ind2','ind3'])
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As with most selection from a DataFrame, you can use a mask or an indexer (`loc` in this case).

To get the mask, you can use `get_level_values` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html)) on the MultiIndex followed by `isin` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html)).

```
m = df.index.get_level_values('ind3').isin(['s1', 's3'])
df[m].reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
```

To use `loc`:

```
df.loc[(slice(None), slice(None), ['s1', 's3']), :].reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
```

both output

```
           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
1    6       10     8
2    7       20     6
5    10      60     0
```

Note: the `loc` way can also be written as seen in Alberto Garcia-Raboso's answer. Many people prefer that syntax as it is more consistent with `loc` syntax for an `Index`. Both syntax styles are discussed in [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Notice I'm looking for a result w.o. 'ind3'.

Answer (score 10):

You can use an `IndexSlice`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
result = df.loc[idx[:, :, ['s1', 's3']], idx[:]]
result.index = result.index.droplevel('ind3')
print(result)
```

Output:

```
           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
1    6       10     8
2    7       20     6
5    10      60     0
```

The second line above can also be written as

```
result = df.loc(axis=0)[idx[:, :, ['s1', 's3']]]
```

Comment: `IndexSlice` - nice!

Comment: @AlbertoGarcia-Raboso Thanks for your reply! 2nd answer was first so I approved it, but yours works as well.

Comment: That should be the chosen answer. Beautiful!